# How to delete zero rows and zero colomns of a matrix in C programming

Tags: c, matrix

Its easy to delete zero rows or colomn in matlab but I am stuck with this problem with my current c code that I have to remove all zero rows and colomns to make my solver more faster. I couldn't find any simple way. Could you help me in any convenient way?

Comment: How did you get "rows" and "columns" in your C code? Are you using an array?

Comment: I am sorry I was try to say in a matrix

Comment: What exactly do you mean by remove them? As in make the matrix smaller?

Comment: You need to show us the code for your matrix implementation

Comment: if you dont want to make extra memory copying operation, you need to shift all the values up and save that array is smaller

Comment: okay, suppose, I have a tri-diagonal matrix, A=diag{-1 2 -1}. For some boundary condition, the first row and colomn will be zero and also the last row and colomn will be zero. Now I need to remove these two rows and two colomn. I hope if you(@Soren) r in computation u have seen such kind of zero rows and colomns a lot. Thats why i asked this question. In matlab we do just: A=A(any(A'),any(A))

Comment: Im not questioning the reasion you are asking the question, however this is a programming forum, and we are not able to help you without some specific code -- C != Mathlab

Comment: There is no "matrix" in C. There are *arrays*. Is that what you're using?

Comment: It all depends on how you have implemented your matrix. Did you make provision for this in the first place? If not it is going to be difficult and/or computational expensive.

Comment: If you would *fix* the question to address the issues pointed out in the comments I could vote for it. People aren't writing them to put you down, man, they're trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For removing *only* leading and trailing rows and columns

We can implement a matrix n a way that makes these operations fairly efficient.

You allocate a large block to hold the maximal amount of data as if it were a 2D array (`[][]`), and do a

```
typedef struct {
   size_t aJ;      /* Allocated row length. Needed for computing positions */
   size_t uI, uJ;  /* Number of row/cols in use currently. For range checking */
   size_t oI, oJ;  /* Offset to the start of the first used row/col */
   double *matrixA /* the storage */
} MatrixT;
```

You will need to write initialization and cleanup routines. Old c hands will note that we could use the array trick here (or the spiffy new variable length member facility)

Accessing element (i,j) goes something like

```
double* element(MatrixT*this, size_t i, size_t j) {
  double* base = this->matrixA + oI*aJ + oJ;
  /* range checking if desired */
  return (base + i*aJ + j);
}
```

This has about twice the complexity of element access from a normal 2D array and can be simplified to a single line at the cost of a little clarity (but your compiler might do that for you).

Removal of rows and columns involves decrementing the appropriate "use value" and also the appropriate "offset" value if you are taking it from the front.

Because the structure is more complicated and requires more bookkeeping than a plain old 2D array you'll want to wrap all operation on it up in functions.

---

Old Fortran77 programers may recognize this as a re-implementation of the  *"passing a contiguous sub-array to a function"* idiom.

Comment: There is a lesson here about asking questions, BTW, the limitation of your requirements to only the leading and trailing row/columns is important.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way will be to traverse row-wise and then column-wise, check for zero, if true replace that row/column with the last one and delete the last one (free() if its dynamic and m-- or n-- if static)

Comment: Expensive if the matrix is implemented as a 2D array. Reliable, but expensive.

Comment: I know its expensive, any other way you know @dmckee ?

Comment: It is easy enough to build a implementation that is optimized for deleting *either* rows or columns, but generally the thing to do is ask *"What's the real goal here?"* and work on solving *that* efficiently.